# Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

I am trying to find only new tweets using Twitter Search.  For example:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search?tag=bruins&lang=en&rpp=100&result_type=recent&since=22451745267388417
```

does not pull any tweets, however, if you remove the since portion, there are tweets that have occurred more recently.

My question is this.  What am I doing wrong?  Given the documentation located [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search), I feel like I am following their guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states:

```
since: Optional. Returns tweets with since the given date.  Date should be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
Example: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter&since=2010-02-28
```

So you should be using:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search?tag=bruins&lang=en&rpp=100&result_type=recent&since=2010-12-31
```